# JSOUP extract an absolute URL in Android

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I've been looking everywhere. Tried a lot of "solutions" but none of 'em helped.
I need to extract url address of sub-website from html code. The code contains a lot of url's so I need to shorten the result list somehow so it leaves only the links that I need.

Details:

```
 <li class="container results-list-item clear-me ">
            <div class="job-offer-content container h-card">
                <div class="position-head container">
                  <div class="container  ">
                      <h2 class="p-job-title">
                          <a href="/praca/android-developer-junior-senior/wroclaw/11636002" rel="nofollow" 
                          title="praca Android developer (junior/senior) dolnośląskie" class="job-offer ">
                              <strong class="keyword">Android</strong> <strong class="keyword">developer</strong> (junior/senior)
                          </a>
                      </h2>
                          <h3 class="p-name company">
                                  <a href="/pracodawca/starware-firma-informatyczna-praca/843242">
                                      Starware Firma Informatyczna
                              </a>
                          </h3>
```

It is only a part of html code. As I said, it contains a lot of url so ideas like `doc.select("a").first();` will not help.

I want to extract all url from section `<h2 class="p-job-title">` (it happens multiple times in code, because it is a result of search on certain website) I tried also `doc.select("h2.p-job-title a[href]");` but the output is `Android developer (junior/senior)` and I need `/pracodawca/starware-firma-informatyczna-praca/843242` and in the absolute form at best )I think that www.mywebsite + url would by just made by some concat or something so it shouldn't be to hard).

EDIT: My whole activity class' code

```
public class ListaActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    StartActivity startActiv;
    private List<String> mLista = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView mListView;
    private MiastaListAdapter mAdapter;
    public Elements jobName, jobName2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_miast);  
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_miast);  
        new NewThread().execute();
        mAdapter = new MiastaListAdapter(this, mLista);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            String doURLwork = startActiv.nazwaStanowiska;
            String doURLplace = startActiv.nazwaMiejscowosci;

            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://www.infopraca.pl/praca?q=" + doURLwork + "&lc=" + doURLplace)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0").get();

                jobName = doc.select("h2.p-job-title a[href]"); //infopraca

                    for (Element jobNames : jobName) {
                        mLista.add(jobNames.text() + "\n");
                    }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your selection is wrong, you should select "h3 a[href]"

Comment: It didn't change a thing. The output is now "Starware Firma Informatyczna", but i need to get a URL.

Comment: Can you please show us the exact code you are using in a properly formatted manner?

Comment: This is the website from which code I need to extract hrefs:   http://www.infopraca.pl/praca?q=android+developer&lc=Wroclaw

Comment: You are trying to get text from your element. so obviously jobNames.text(); will return text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get Text from your selected elements. `mLista.add(jobNames.text() + "\n");` which is wrong. if you need links you have to get `attribute` `href` from your selected elements.

try something like this

```
Elements class= doc.getElementsByClass("p-job-title");
Elements link= class.select("a");
String url = link.attr("href");
```

Comment: So obvious, yet I couldn't find it! Thanks :)

Comment: For people searching for an answer from question title: `attr("href")` can return relative path. If we want to make sure that we will get absolute path we need to use `attr("abs:href")`.